# How to update nodejs on mac?

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install nodejs on mac using homebrew, but when I run the command:

```
brew install node
```

I get the following error:

```
Beginning with 0.8.0, this recipe now comes with npm.
It appears you already have npm installed at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm.
To use the npm that comes with this recipe, first uninstall npm with
`npm uninstall npm -g`, then run this command again.

If you would like to keep your installation of npm instead of
using the one provided with homebrew, install the formula with
the `--without-npm` option.
```

but when I run:

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
```

I get:

```
sudo: npm: command not found
```

When I run the command `npm`, I get:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

so I'm not sure whether it's actually installed or not.

My node version is 0.8.22 (I have no idea where it came from). How should I update it to the latest version?

Comment: If you use homebrew just use it and nothing else. I would try to uninstall using brew first. Also did yiu install node via home-brew?

Answer (score 2):

Is `/usr/local/bin/npm` a broken symlink? That would make `sudo npm` print an error like `command not found` and `npm` print an error like `No such file or directory`.

You could try creating a new symlink for node:

```
$ rm /usr/local/bin/npm; brew unlink node; brew link node
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.5... 4 links removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.5... 5 symlinks created
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/npm uninstall npm -g
```

Or use `/usr/local/opt/node/bin/npm`:

```
$ ls -l `brew --prefix node`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 lauri  admin  21 Jun 14 18:27 /usr/local/opt/node -> ../Cellar/node/0.10.5
$ sudo /usr/local/opt/node/bin/npm uninstall npm -g
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is years old, but after dealing with these sorts of file permission and package manager problems myself for many years, a buddy of mine and I created a rather simple solution that works without `sudo`, and without relying on `brew` or other package managers.

## Install with `webi`

On Mac or Linux:

```bsh
curl -s https://webinstall.dev/node@stable | bash
```

Or, on Windows 10 (which now includes `curl.exe` - so no msysgit or cygwin needed):

```bsh
curl.exe -sA "MS" https://webinstall.dev/node@stable | powershell
```

More info at https://webinstall.dev/node (also has a link to the source for the bash and powershell)

## Upgrade / Switch Versions

And then you can switch versions (upgrade, downgrade, etc) like this:

```bsh
webi node     # 'stable' is the default tag
```

```bsh
webi node@lts # long-term support
```

```bsh
webi node@v10 # specifically the latest of v10
```

## Doing the same by hand

`webi` is just a small helper / bootstrap script in `bash` (or `powershell` on Windows 10), and you could do the same by hand:

- Check the node.js releases API: https://nodejs.org/dist/index.tab
- Get the desired version: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/
- Unpack to `$HOME/.local/opt/node`
- Add `$HOME/.local/opt/node/bin` to your `PATH`

  - (in `.zshrc`, `.bashrc`, `.profile`, the Windows Registry, or with `pathman`)
- On macOS 10.14+ you may need to use

  - `xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine ~/.local/opt/node/bin/node`

Then when you need to update versions, remove the node directory (`rm -rf ~/.local/opt/node`) and then repeat the above steps with the new version.

Note: This requires re-installing any global tools, such as `jshint` or `prettier`.

Comment: If you keep getting downvotes you may consider removing the parts expalining how to apply to solution to Windows and Linux systems.

Comment: I don't mind downvotes. Haters gonna hate. I believe it's valuable to know that this particular solution also works on Windows and Linux and I stand by that.

Comment: P.S. Thank you for your concern and your suggestion. If you personally find it distracting from the solution I'd like to better understand that thought process and it may drive me to change the answer.

Comment: Personally I don’t mind. But AD is focused on Apple products, and answers tend to attract downvoted if they specifically are tailored for other environments as well

Comment: Well, I suppose we can't all be tolerant and inclusive all of the time. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For me, NVM solved all my problems with complexity in nodejs, like "node version", "npm version", "yarn version". Installing anything in nodejs is super simple using nvm.

You can install via Homebrew using this [formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/nvm)

```
brew install nvm
```

then update it with the install version  you want by writing:

```
$ nvm use 16
Now using node v16.9.1 (npm v7.21.1)
$ node -v
v16.9.1
$ nvm use 14
Now using node v14.18.0 (npm v6.14.15)
$ node -v
v14.18.0
$ nvm install 12
Now using node v12.22.6 (npm v6.14.5)
$ node -v
v12.22.6
```